# ajax requests to Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

In my app.js file in Node.js I have this:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

which I thought was good enough but whenever I submit data via jQuery/Ajax the response is an empty object.

After doing the below however, it now get the data from `req.body`. But, I thought that in the newer versions of Express it was not necessary to do this anymore?

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

The Ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/endpoint',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {key: key}
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

Comment: both .json and .urlencoded are implemented, but you still need to do app.use(expess.json()) see docs https://expressjs.com/en/api.html, sidenote, dont hardcode `http://localhost:8000` in your ajax call

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes, I am already using `app.use(express.json());` but as mentioned the response is empty. Only when I add the bodyParser code do I then get the actual response. Are you saying I still need to do the bodyParser as well as `app.use(express.json()); ` ie: I have to have both? When using React I don't need bodyParser included. Thanks for the sidenote, it was just for this example, I won't hardcode it in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with how you're making your ajax requests. `express.json` expects the Content-Type of the request to be JSON and I believe if you check your network call on the browser DevTools you'll see that the Content-Type of your request is not JSON.

You need to set the headers in your ajax request and also send valid JSON data like so

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
data: JSON.stringify({key: key})
```

Then the `express.json` middleware will handle the request and you won't need to use the bodyParser lines of code you're using.